# Get table definition in oracle sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ddl, database-metadata

I'm new to sql and I have created table using `create table table_name`.
And now I want to get this table definition or let's say source code, I know command desc table_name but that's not what I want. Could you help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the function: `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`

http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html